# permission denied while execute command on docker container

Tags: bash, docker, permissions

I'm trying to execute command on a docker container from the docker host but got permission denied.
I want to send notification to docker log once new version uploaded.
Tried to use --user appuser, without success.

my command:
`docker exec --workdir /app my-container printf 'NEW VERSION UPLOADED %s\n'  "$(printenv VERSION)" >> /proc/1/fd/1`

the error i got:
`-bash: /proc/1/fd/1: Permission denied`

How can i do that?

Thank you

Comment: Try with `--user root` and bash -c 'printf ...  >> /proc/1/fd/1'. If you dont put redirect inside quote it will try to write to  /proc/1/fd/1 of the host and not the container

Comment: How would you execute this command inside some other process without Docker?  What is your eventual goal with this setup?

Comment: Try running the command in a bash shell docker exec --workdir /app my-container bash -c 'printf "NEW VERSION UPLOADED %s\n" "$(printenv VERSION)" >> /proc/1/fd/1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `docker exec --workdir /app my-container printf 'NEW VERSION UPLOADED %s\n'  "$(printenv VERSION)" >> /proc/1/fd/1` will try to write to /proc/1/fd/1 of your host and not to the container.

Also appuser don't have the permission to write to proc/fd, so **--user root** must be used if there is **USER appuser** in the Dockerfile (which means that the default user is appuser).

So your command should be:

```bash
docker exec --workdir /app my-container --user root \
 /bin/sh -c 'printf "NEW VERSION UPLOADED %s\n"  "$(printenv VERSION)" >> /proc/1/fd/1'
```

Comment: Note also that in this case **--workdir /app** is not necessary.